# Python - More efficient way to loop through matrices

Tags: python, numpy, loops, matrix

I have

- an (height x width x 3) RGB image ***img***
- a (256 x 256 x 256) matrix ***color_mapping*** mapping colors
- a (height x width) matrix ***pixel_result*** which I want to fill with the elements mapped with ***color_mapping*** for each pixel of the image

How can I fill that last matrix efficiently?

So far, I simply run through all the pixels in **for loops**, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it

```
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        pixel_result[j,i] = color_mapping[img[j,i,0],img[j,i,1],img[j,i,2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this by subscripting the `color_mapping`:

```
pixel_result = color_mapping[img[:,:,0], img[:,:,1], img[:,:,2]]
```

For example if test the performance with:

```
>>> def f():
...   for i in range(width):
...     for j in range(height):
...         pixel_result[j,i] = color_mapping[img[j,i,0],img[j,i,1],img[j,i,2]]
... 
>>> def g():
...     pixel_result = color_mapping[img[:,:,0], img[:,:,1], img[:,:,2]]
>>> color_mapping = np.random.randn(256,256,256)
```

Then for a small image: `img = np.random.randint(0, 256, (12, 7, 3))`, we get:

```
>>> timeit(f, number=10000)
0.5247259399620816
>>> timeit(g, number=10000)
0.032307324931025505
```

For larger images, like `img = np.random.randint(0, 256, (1920, 1080, 3))`, we get:

```
>>> timeit(f, number=10)
18.934733690926805
>>> timeit(g, number=10)
0.5807857210747898
```

or for a 72×128 image:

```
>>> timeit(f, number=100)
0.6014469779329374
>>> timeit(g, number=100)
0.011570235947147012
```

Comment: It's actually 15 times slower

Comment: @user3548298: the assignment is of course done *once*, so *not* in a `for` loop. I've tested this for both small and large images, and got a speedup of approximately 32 for large images, and 16 for small images.

Comment: Oh ... right I'm an idiot... I forgot to take it out of the loop

Comment: @user3548298: you noticed that there are two loops that you need to remove? :) I got a speedup of 52x for that.

Comment: Do you think it could still be easy to speed it up even more? Maybe using some image processing libraries which map pixels to other pixels colors (like some kind of colormap). I'm assuming those use hardware acceleration. In my case, the mapping is done to float values.

Comment: @user3548298: not with numpy. Here I used floating point values as well (notice that `np.random.randn(..)`). You can try to use a tool like `cudamap` to process this on a GPU.